# Update record with additional params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently working on my new web application. My customers can make a reservation and afterwards they get redirect to a form, where they can submit additional information, like: description, website, email, password...

The record is already created with the `create` method, after a successful payment the customer is redirect to my `submit` method. I already tried `@reservation.update(reservation_params)` but this didn't work.

My routes:

```
resources :reservations, only: [:approve, :decline, :submit] do
 member do
  match 'submit', via: [:get, :post]
 end
end
```

My Reservations controller:

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :authenticate_user!
 before_action :is_admin, only: [:approve, :decline, :your_reservations]
 before_action :set_reservation, only: [:approve, :decline, :submit]

def create
service = Service.find(params[:service_id])

if current_user.admin?
  flash[:alert] = "Du kannst nicht dein eigenes Angebot kaufen"
elsif current_user.stripe_id.blank?
  flash[:alert] = "Füge eine Zahlungsmehtode hinzu"
  return redirect_to payment_method_path
else
  @reservation = current_user.reservations.build
  @reservation.service = service
  @reservation.price = service.price

  if @reservation.Bearbeitung!
    flash[:notice] = "Ihre Anfrage wurde erfolgreich versendet"
    ReservationMailer.confirm_email_to_guest(@reservation.user, service).deliver
    confirm_sms(service, @reservation)
  else
    charge(service, @reservation)
  end

end
redirect_to submit_reservation_path(@reservation)
end

def submit
 redirect_to root_path, alert: "Du hast keine Berechtigung!" unless current_user.id == @reservation.user_id
end

def set_reservation
 @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id])
end
end
```

My submit.html.erb:

```
    <%= form_for submit_reservation_path, method: :post do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Aufgabe</label>
        <%= f.text_field :description, placeholder: "Aufgabe", required: true, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="text-center"><%= f.submit "Veröffentlichen", class: "btn btn-primary btn-block" %></div>
    <% end %>
```

I deleted the `params.permit(:description)`, since it wasn't working. I expected that the additional params `description`,`website` are inserted into my reservations table, but that was not the case.

I got the this error a few times:

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Reservation with 'id'={"id"=>"23"}):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not reference the reservation object you want:

```
form_for submit_reservation_path, method: :post do |f|
```

change it like this:

```
form_for @reservation, url: submit_reservation_path(@reservation), method: :post do |f|
```

Now the url will be fine and the id param should be the right one.

Then, in your submit action, you can update the record with `@reservation.update(reservation_params)`

---

Just two tips, personally, I would move that "redirect if not the current user" line to a before_action to clean that up and also use different actions for the get and post methods, something like this:

```
resources :reservations, only: [:approve, :decline, :submit] do
  member do
    get :submit
    post :submit, action: :do_submit
  end
end

#controller
before_action :set_reservation, only: [:approve, :decline, :submit, :do_submit]
before_action :check_reservation_ownership, only: [:submit, :do_submit]

def submit
end

def do_submit
  @reservation.update_attributes(reservation_params)
  render action: :submit #or redirect, or something else
end

private
def check_reservation_ownership
  redirect_to root_path, alert: "Du hast keine Berechtigung!" unless current_user.id == @reservation.user_id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you need an update action in your reservation controller.
Your create action, creates the reservation but if the next form asks for more information, so to me it's an update...

you could write something like this

```
def update
 if @reservation.update_attributes(reservation_params)
   redirect_to your_path
 else
  render :new
 end
end

   private

   def reservation_params
     params.require(:reservation).permit( all your attributes including, :description, :website)
   end
```